# Will the AOZ2264 Vcc work on 3v3?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

It's weird to have to provide [the AOZ2264](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ2264QI-19.pdf)  with its own logic Vcc, which is something I haven't needed to consider with other chips. But, fine, whatever.

The specifications for Vcc are painfully sparse:

> Supply Input for analog functions. Bypass VCC to AGND with a 1μF~10μF ceramic
> capacitor. Place the capacitor close to VCC pin.

[image: absmax]

It appears only twice in the block diagram; I'd bet there are other undisclosed uses:

[image: block diagram]

It's shown as the external pullup source for PGOOD but I'm just going to leave that open.

Otherwise, the biggest concern is that the majority of the device's behaviour is specified assuming Vcc=5V; but there's nowhere explicitly stating that that needs to be the nominal voltage. There's no statement of minimum Vcc. How risky is it to provide 3.3V? This would be very convenient as I already have an on-board 3v3 rail, and also EN to this chip is going to use 3.3V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because the UVLO will kick in. It's designed to see +5 on Vcc. From your linked datasheet:

[image]

Comment: OK. For some reason I had originally read that as "UVLO of the primary input" and not "UVLO of Vcc". Sigh, so I guess I need to throw in another linear regulator.

Comment: @Reinderien Or you could use a different converter? Are you constrained to using only the AOZ2264, or could you use some other part with equivalent functionality? (I know Maxim and TI have a lot of affordable buck controller options, and good simulation support)

Comment: It's a little bit of a struggle to find a device that either has LDO mode, or (as the AOS SMPS do) Vout/Vin up to 0.85. If you have any suggestions I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be any risk, but the circuit won't work.

[image]

If you supply it with less than 4.2 V, the UVLO will prevent anything from working.